# What is the difference between the "Home and Student" and standard versions of Office 2010 programs?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office-2010

I was shopping the [Microsoft Store](http://store.microsoft.com/microsoft/Office-Office-2010-Stand-Alone-Programs/category/211) for a copy of Word 2010.  At the top of the page, they sell "Word 2010" for $139.99.  At the bottom of the page they sell "Word Home and Student 2010" for $119.99.  The details and product descriptions for both versions look exactly the same.  There is a similar situation where "Home and Student" versions of Excel and PowerPoint are offered with no easily identifiable differences in features.

So what is the $20 difference between these two programs?

Comment: The cheapest and best option the Office 2010 Home and Student. It is $120, the same price as the stand-alone Word Home and Student. That is if you plan on buying the Home and Student version of the Word stand-alone. The whole Home and Student suite will come with Power Point, OneNote, and Excel along with Word 2010. In-addition, it comes with one license/key that can be used to install on 3 different system _with in the household_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the only difference is [the license](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/products/office-2010-frequently-asked-questions-HA101674631.aspx#Pricing_Office_2010_5):

> Office Home and Student 2010 is
>   licensed only for non-commercial use
>   by households. It cannot be used for
>   any commercial, nonprofit, or
>   revenue-generating activities, by
>   schools or academic institutions, or
>   by any government organization.

Comment: This is correct. It has to do with the license. It you choose Home and Student then it is non-commercial. The other stand-alone is for commercial use.